# Two moving bodies

Tags: parametric, parametrization

I'm doing parametric equations, however I'm stuck on last question from my lab sheet. Can someone help?

Consider two moving bodies whose positions are given by the following sets of parameterised equations:
Body 1: x = 7t - 3    y = 5 + t - t ^2 
Body 2: x = 6 - 2t    y = (t - 3)^2 + 1

Will these two bodies hit each other? If, so what's the position of the collision?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The bodies do collide if they can have the same abscissa and ordinate at the same time.

They have the same abscissa when

$$7t-3=6-2t.$$

You should be able to finish.

> $$t=1,\\x_1=x_2=4,\\y_1=y_2=5.$$

Comment: @Raffaele: be serious and just admit that you were wrong. In this case there are infinitely many "collisions" on $x$, not just one.